# How can I automate running py code (via github) on my ec2 instance via AWS Lambda or other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have code on my github repo that analyses a bunch of images and creates a bunch of reports essentially. It connects to my AWS s3 buckets to pull the images and push the reports back to it. To execute the code currently I ssh onto an EC2 instance and send the command myself.

I'm trying to automate this process whereby when images have finished uploading into a certain s3 bucket the ec2 instance is automatically started and the py code on github is run automatically. My ideal automated workflow looks like this:

- Batch of images upload to s3 bucket
- Once finished, trigger allows ec2 instance to start
- Command to run py code on github sent automatically, to analyse images
- Reports saved into another s3 bucket, ec2 instance stops

Currently I'm using AWS Lambda functions to start/stop EC2 instance based on a s3 trigger, but I can't quite figure out how to use AWS Lambda to send commands to the EC2 instance to run the analysis. My code on github is probably too large to put onto a AWS Lambda function itself (over 1000 lines long), which is why I'm trying to find a way to keep it hosted on github but run it automated from EC2.

I've researched into all sorts, Eventbridge, SQS/SNS etc but haven't found any information that can help me with this specific problem (yet) - any help greatly appreciated even if it's a brand new route away from AWS Lambda.

Tried setting up AWS Lambda function to remote onto EC2, haven't attempted other paths yet as can't see anything to suggest they'll produce the desired outcome.

Comment: "over 1000 lines long", that is far from the limit of Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using EC2, I would go with EventBridge -> Batch

1. Create a Batch [job definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-job-definition-EC2.html) (basically, a docker image plus the EC2 configuration), and a [queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-job-queue.html). You can also run your batch jobs in Fargate containers or EKS pods.
2. Create a bus on EventBridge, set up an [EventBridge rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch-cwe-target.html) to listen to S3 events on this bus and post the events to the Batch queue.
3. Set up your S3 bucket to [post the events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventBridge.html) to the EventBridge bus.

Batch will create and tear down your EC2 instances or containers as needed automatically.

There is a chance that you can move your code into Lambda. Basically, just about any code that does not rely on the filesystem and is not running external executables is a good fit for Lambda.

You can still do the filesystem and external executables (Linux only) in Lambda with a little bit of effort, but it's harder to do that and it's against Lambda's philosophy. It's just easier to use Batch jobs if that's something you need.

Lambda can be [triggered directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) by S3 uploads.

Comment: First off thank you for the swift response! 

Couple questions: Does Batch create then delete EC2 instances when utilised or am I mis-understanding? So far I've relied on my existing EC2 instance so was hoping to just rely on that again but can always change.

Sounds obvious but what falls under external executables if I was going to attempt to move the code into Lambda? The code sets up docker images to be able to run external software for image processing and analysis. It organises s3 buckets, prints reports back to s3 and tasks like that.

Comment: @MRo: yes Batch creates and destroys instances as needed, if you use the [managed environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environments.html#managed_compute_environments). If you can tolerate delays or jobs failures mid-way, you can use price-capped Spot instances which is way cheaper than On-Demand (the long-term kind people usually use).

Comment: @MRo: if you (or the libraries you're importing) are doing something like `subprocess.call("imagemagick", …)` within your python code to process images, you are using an external executable (namely, imagemagick)

Comment: Great thanks again, if the software I was using was an API, so creating the task within a docker image created within the code, can that be contained within Lambda?

Comment: If all your dependencies are the Python runtime and libraries, that's a clear cut use case for Lambda